# The post a duplicate link directs to as been removed for reasons of moderation

Tags: support, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

Recently, I have been trying to learn about PHP and using/storing passwords securely.

I came across this post: [Exactly how do I use blowfish in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806779/exactly-how-do-i-use-blowfish-in-php?rq=1)

Which is marked as a duplicate of:  [best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords)

But that post has been closed due to reasons of moderation.  Shouldn't there be some kind of check in place to make sure this doesn't happen?  Or at least, should the post [Exactly how do I use blowfish in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806779/exactly-how-do-i-use-blowfish-in-php?rq=1) still be marked as a duplicate since the question is supposedly a duplicate of a question that no longer exists?

Comment: If a question is both off topic and a duplicate it will be closed as duplicate preferentially, if the duplicate is deleted it is still off topic (this one is really broad). That said I have voted to reopen for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords) was itself a duplicate, so it really never should have been deleted to begin with since it serves to help people find the canonical post.  I've undeleted that and opened/closed [Exactly how do I use blowfish in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806779/exactly-how-do-i-use-blowfish-in-php?rq=1&noredirect=1) so they both point to the same post.